# How to disable the clt+u for browser?

Tags: javascript, html, events

when i browse for to disable the right click and short cut o the browser, found the solution in this url

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/138420/how-to-disable-view-source-and-ctrlc-from-a-site

here is the script working for disable the right-click but not for (control+u) shortcut.
how could disable the keyboard events means (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> event):

```
<script>
     var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
    if(navigator.appName == "Netscape")               
   document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
    function mischandler(){
     return false;
  }
      function mousehandler(e){
     var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
          var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
        if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
       }
        document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
       document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
        document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
</script>
```

Comment: Even if `CTRL+U` is disabled, they could still access your source in a lot of ways. There just isn't any way to stop it completely (and really no good reason to do it). Put your time into making a great website instead of trying to create some kind of fake security.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if ! IE]><!-->
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode===85){e.preventDefault();return false;}
});
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

It's enclosed in a conditional comment that prevents IE from parsing the script(IE<9 doesn't support addEventlistener and AFAIK IE doesnt use  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> for viewsource)

However, I wouldn't suggest to use it, you'll never know which shortcuts are bound to the browser(although it seems that the most browsers use this shortcut for viewsource, it could be that the shortcut has bee modified by the user)

Users that are interested in the source of the page will not have any problems to access the source somehow.

The only rational reason to use it IMHO would be when you have another application bound to this shortcut(e.g. an editor where you use it for text-formatting)

Comment: This doesn't work in at least Opera. You just cannot capture all shortcuts.